# Adding column headers to csv file using python, reading json

Tags: python, json, csv

So i have a program that reads json, flattens it and dumps csv:

```
import json
import unicodecsv as csv
import sys
import glob
import os
from flatten_json import flatten_json

def createcolumnheadings(cols):
    #create column headings
    columns = cols.keys()
    columns = list( set( columns ) )
    return columns

doOnce=True

path=os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

for f in glob.glob("smallR.txt"):
    fName=os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    out_file= open( 'csv/' + fName+'.csv', 'wb' )
    csv_w = csv.writer( out_file, delimiter="\t", encoding='utf-8'  )

    with open(f, 'r') as handle:
        for line in handle:   
            data = json.loads(line)        
            flatdata =flatten_json(data)             
            if doOnce:
                columns=createcolumnheadings(flatdata) 
                columns.insert(0,'racism')
                csv_w.writerow( columns)                
                doOnce=False
            flatdata['racism']= 0
            csv_w.writerow(flatdata.get(x, u'') for x in columns)
```

This works OK, with one problem.
My program just takes the column headings from the first line in smallR.txt (plus it adds a 'Racism' column).

Some of the latter data (smallR.txt [here](http://dropcanvas.com/q12y4)) has different columns. This results in output not quite right, see small.csv [here](http://dropcanvas.com/q12y4).

Is there an  easy way to adapt my program to handle new column headings found on later lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to scan the whole file first, in order to get all the possible columns:

```
with open(f, 'r') as handle:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]

columns = ['racism'] + list({k for entry in data for k in entry.keys()})

csv_w.writerow(columns)
for entry in entries:
    csv_w.writerow(entry.get(c, '') for c in columns)
```

This **loads all data in memory**. If this is not acceptable to you, you might read the file twice: one to get the columns, another to read and write:

```
with open(f, 'r') as handle:
    columns = ['racism'] + list({k for line in handle for k in json.load(line).keys()})
csv_w.write(columns)

with open(f, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        entry = json.loads(line)
        csv_w.write(entry.get(c, '') for c in columns)
```

The *flatten_json* function definition is missing so I can only guess what it does.

Comment: Thanks Javier, the files are huge so I will give your second method a go. Flatten_json is an import from [here](https://medium.com/@amirziai/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10#.v8fb0z7bt)